# How calculate $Time$ variable for name of dash media segments?

Tags: url, video, segment, mpeg-dash, iptv

I have an MPD playlist. I'd like to find out what are URLs of media segments for next period.
The example is like this

```
     <SegmentTemplate timescale="10000000" initialization="Video-$RepresentationID$-init.mp4" media="Video-$RepresentationID$-$Time$.mp4">
      <SegmentTimeline>
        <S t="2083838574453329" d="100053337" />
        <S d="100053332" r="1" />
        <S d="99839999" />
        <S d="100053337" />
      </SegmentTimeline>
    </SegmentTemplate>
```

How calculate $Time$ variabel for each period of dash segment?

Answer (score -1):

The DASH specification is freely available at https://www.iso.org/standard/79329.html and clearly documents how to determine the URL of any segment listed in the manifest.

Edit 09/08/23: A newer version of the specification is publicly available to download at no cost at https://www.iso.org/standard/83314.html (ignore the option to purchase and follow the link to the ITTF download page)

Comment: My claim is absolutely correct - the linked page clearly states that the "The electronic version of this International Standard can be downloaded from the ISO/IEC Information Technology Task Force (ITTF) web site.", and following the download link leads to a PDF and accompanying materials that can be downloaded at no cost.